# Use PreparedStatement to build a query

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I was wondering if using PreparedStatement.setString() was a good idea (possible, sensible?) to dynamically build a query.

For example :

sql code:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.category = ? ?
```

java code:

```
ps.setString(1,"category1");
ps.setString(2,"AND table1.category = 'category2'");
```

Also, would it be possible to do something like:

```
ps.setString(1,"category1");
ps.setString(2," AND table1.category = ?");
ps.setString(3,"category2");
```

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? Will it actually work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, **NO**.

PreparedStatements are strictly for values only. Table Names and Column Names (*as well as conditions in your example*) are not allowed. So the best way to do is to concatenate it with the string.

```
String others = " AND table1.category = ?";
String query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.category = ? " + others;
```

java code:

```
ps.setString(1,"category1");
ps.setString(2,"category2");
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do it this way.

Comment: @BenoitParis or directly `String query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.category = ? AND table1.category = ?";`

Comment: Also as per OP's code `AND table1.category = ?` would be in single quotes so the generated query won't make sense

Comment: @BhavikShah I know, it is just an example to show that you can concatenate ***other strings*** but not to add conditions as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you put inside setString will go within single quotes ' ' and will not be interpreted as a query.